# Invalid escape sequence to run Linux command in JAVA

Tags: java, linux

I need to execute this Linux command in Java using BufferedReader:

```
grep 'auth\.' /var/lib/iscsi/nodes/10.1.1.36/*/default
```

What I was trying to execute is :

```
String inputThis = "";
String executeThis = "grep" + " " + "'auth\\.'" + " "
                        + "/var/lib/iscsi/nodes/10.1.1.36" + "/*/default";

Process process = ServerHelper.callProcessWithInput(executeThis, inputThis);

BufferedReader stdOutput = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

try {
    logger.debug("stdOutput for editing:");

    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdOutput.readLine()) != null) {
        logger.info("####################" + s);
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    logger.fatal(e);
}
```

It has **no** error warning: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

But it works incorrect. I run the command in Linux terminal, it works fine and returned the desired results without error message. But when I execute the above code, the result is null. If you check the the error message,it says:

```
####################grep: /var/lib/iscsi/nodes/10.1.1.36/*/default: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to modify the string?

Update:
Figured it out! We cannot use "*" in the string, java cannot detect it.Just

```
executeThis = "ls" + " " + "/var/lib/iscsi/nodes/"+ 10.1.1.36;
```

to find what * is, and

```
executeThis = "cat" + " " + "/var/lib/iscsi/nodes/" + 10.1.1.36 + "/" + myString + "/default";
```

Comment: The code you've posted does not produce the error you're talking about. What do you mean by "it works incorrect"? What *does* it do, and what did you *expect* it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just specified the error above.

Comment: All right, next question: what do you mean, "execute it using BufferedReader"? BufferedReader cannot execute system calls. Can you show how you actually call the process?

Comment: See above changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

exec(String[] cmdarray)
Executes the specified command and arguments in a separate process.

**`process.exec("new String[]{"grep", "'auth\.'", "/var/lib/iscsi/nodes/10.1.1.36/*/default"});`**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I can only write it in a whole string, how to modify my string? Because I cannot do your ways in my project.

Comment: this will compile? the \ in `"'auth\.'"` is unescaped.

Comment: @typeofprogrammer  Formulate the string like this using the spilt functionality using the space as delimiter.